# keep latest record based on multiple grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wrote a multi-stage pipeline to arrive at this set of documents:

```
{'_id': '1234'),
  'info': [{'type': 'patient',
    'patient_id': 'p1'},
   {'type': 'doc',
    'doc_id': 'd1'},
   {'type': 'ldlc',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 29, 12, 7, 23),
    'val': 136},
   {'type': 'bp',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 25, 4, 2, 27),
    'val': [{'dias': 74}, {'sys': 105}]}]},
{'_id': '1235'),
  'info': [{'type': 'patient',
    'patient_id': 'p2'},
   {'type': 'doc',
    'doc_id': 'd1'},
   {'type': 'ldlc',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 21, 30, 34),
    'val': 153},
   {'type': 'bp',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 3, 18, 3, 12),
    'val': [{'dias': 86}, {'sys': 101}]},
   {'type': 'bp',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 15, 18, 35, 25),
    'val': [{'dias': 85}, {'sys': 108}]},
   {'type': 'ldlc',
    'dt': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 12, 7, 23),
    'val': 144}]}
```

I am using pymongo, hence the datetime objects.

Now in each document I only want to keep the last recorded values (sort by `dt`) for 'ldlc' and 'bp'.

I would prefer it to be as:

```
{
  "_id": '1234',
  "patient_id": "p1",
  "doc_id": "d1".
  "sys": 105,
  "dias": 74,
  "ldlc": 136

},
{
  "_id": '1235',
  "patient_id": "p2",
  "doc_id": "d1".
  "sys": 108,
  "dias": 85,
  "ldlc": 144
}
```

since the source documents are generated in an aggregation pipeline, i want to add $project and $group stages after that in order to product the desired result.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to achieve this use case.

I started with [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to sort based on dates. And then used [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for parallel grouping.Since you need to keep only the latest record, [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) is used to get required values.

Your aggregation can look like below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$info"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "info.dt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "ldlc": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "info.type": "ldlc"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "ldlc": {
              $last: "$info.val"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "bp": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "info.type": "bp"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "bp": {
              $last: "$info.val"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$bp"
        }
      ],
      "others": [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              {
                "info.type": "patient"
              },
              {
                "info.type": "doc"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "ids": {
              $push: {
                p: "$info.patient_id",
                d: "$info.doc_id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$ids"
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$others",
          "$ldlc",
          "$bp"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$data._id",
      "val": {
        $push: {
          patient_id: "$data.ids.p",
          doc_id: "$data.ids.d",
          ldlc: "$data.ldlc",
          dias: "$data.bp.dias",
          sys: "$data.bp.sys"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      "v": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$val",
          "initialValue": {},
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      patient_id: "$v.patient_id",
      doc_id: "$v.doc_id",
      ldlc: "$v.ldlc",
      dias: "$v.dias",
      sys: "$v.sys"
    }
  }
])
```

Check out the query result here: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-2L_VKy3l7S)

PS: This may not be the best approach

Comment: this is great, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!